# Connect to remote PostgreSQL server over Tor? [python] [Tor]

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2, tor

I'm creating a Python 3 spider that scrapes Tor hidden services for useful data. I'm storing this data in a PostgreSQL database using the `psycopg2` library. Currently, the spider script and the database are hosted on the same network, so they have no trouble communicating. However, I plan to migrate the database to a remote server on a VPS so that I can have a team of users running the spider script from a number of remote locations, all contributing to the same database. For example, I could be running the script at my house, my friend could run it from his VPS, and my professor could run the script from a few different systems in the lab at the university, and all of these individual systems could synchronize with the PostgreSQL server runnning on my remote VPS.

This would be easy enough if I simply opened the database VPS to accept connections from anywhere, making the database public. However, I do not want to do this, for security reasons. I know I could tunnel the connection through SSH, but that would require giving each person a username and password that would grant them access to the server itself. I don't wish to do this. I'd prefer simply giving them access to the database without granting access to a shell account.

I'd prefer to limit connections to the local system `127.0.0.1` and create a Tor hidden service .onion address for the database, so that my remote spider clients can connect to the database .onion through Tor.

The problem is, I don't know how to connect to a remote database through a proxy using `psycopg2`. I can connect to remote databases, but I don't see any option for connecting through a proxy.

Does anyone know how this might be done?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Before posting a question, please read [ask]. I'm sure someone will be able to help you if you follow that guide and post a [mcve] that we could help you with

Answer (score 0):

> This would be easy enough if I simply opened the database VPS to accept connections from anywhere

Here lies your issue. Just simply lock down your VPS using `fail2ban` and `ufw`. Create a `ufw` role to only allow connection to your Postgres port from the IP address you want to give access from to that VPS ip address.

This way, you don't open your Postgres port to anyone (from *) but only to a specific other server or servers that you control. This is how you do it. Don't run an onion service to connect Postgres content because that will only complicate things and slow down the reads to your Postgres database that I am assuming an API will be consuming eventually to get to the "useful data" you will be scraping.

I hope that at least points you in the right direction. Your question was pretty general, so I am keeping my answer along the same vein.